# How to run single Jasmine test in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Is it possible to run single [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) test `it` or suite `describe` in IntelliJ from popup menu as it possible with JUnit or TestNG fremeworks?

Now I can only execute tests by running `karma.conf.js` that will grab all specs and run them which is not exactly what I want.

### Updates

This is known **[issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13173)** please upvote it.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need Intellij's help if you are trying to run a single unit test or a single test suite while using [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io). You can do that with their feature of `fit()` and `fdescribe()`. Here, prepending `it(...)` and `describe(...)` with `f` says those are **focused** tests/test suites.

Quoting the [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) (Jasmine 2.1 and above),

> Focusing specs will make it so that they are the only specs that run.
>
> Any spec declared with `fit` is focused.
>   You can focus on a describe with `fdescribe`

Comment: Ok even if I'll change `it` to `fit` is still only one way to run this test by running `karma.conf.js` file right ?

Comment: @AntonDozortsev Yes. Ideally, you should set up a gulp task to run the tests that uses `karma.conf.js` (and generate reports)

Comment: I have this Gulp task it runs during main project build (Maven build). It will be much convenient to run single test using IntelliJ.

Comment: @AntonDozortsev What you can do is set up a run task that runs `gulp test` (or whatever your task name is) and then use `fit(..)` or `fdescribe(..)` for running single test/suite. I use this everyday for a huge project and it works like charm. Why do you want to rely on IntelliJ so much?

Comment: What do you mean saying *set up a run task* ? Yes it works but still I need to edit my specs files and run it through `karma.conf.js` or Gulp task.

Comment: @AntonDozortsev I meant a run task like [this](http://imgur.com/xiAlvMv) which will run your `gulp test` for you on `Ctrl+F5`. It shouldn't be a hazard adding/removing an `f` from your spec, should it?

Comment: One day some one will *push* changes with `f`. Anyway thank you.

Comment: Well for my project, we would immediately know because of unit-test thresholds. And you can't not use it fearing someday someone will forget it in code. Good luck anyway..

Comment: Yes, and then you commit the fdescribe and your ci runs only one spec, bravo

Answer (score 1):

You could follow this issue in YouTrack - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13173.

We have supported `--grep`[1] option for jasmine in karma already.
But there are some open discussions about problems in large projects[2]

[1] - https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/pull/56

[2] - https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1235

Thanks!

Comment: Can I use `--grep` flag in IntelliJ through *Run | Edit Configuration* ?

Answer (score 1):

With WebStorm 2017.1 it's possible to use RunConfiguration producer to run a single Karma test: https://github.com/develar/ij-rc-producer

Comment: New IntelliJ IDEA have this feature ?

Comment: This ij-producer exist from IntelliJ box or it's require additional installation ?

Comment: Make sure Node.js plugin is installed. Then add rc-producer.yml file into .idea: 
`files: ["**/__tests__/**/*", "**/*.spec.*", "**/*.test.*", "!**/node_modules/**/*"]
script: "node_modules/.bin/karma"
lineRegExp: '^\s*(?:test|it|describe)(?:\.[^(]+)?\((?:"|''){1}([^"'']+)'
scriptArgs: ["run", "--", "--grep", "${0}"]
rcName: "${fileNameWithoutExt}.${0}"`

Comment: We use .ipr, not .idea in our project. Can this still work?

Comment: Any idea how to specify the working directory?
`workingDirectory` parameters is not effective.

Comment: Right now, as a working directory, WebStorm uses the directory where the config file is located. Please vote for this feature request if you want to configure working directory in the run/debug configuration: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24223